# Why I can't use HttpContext or HttpCookie? (Asp.Net Core 1.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5

Why can't I use `HttpContext` or `HttpCookie`?
Is there a special using?

My actual usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

My namespace:

```
namespace eCoffee.Main
```

My class + methods:

```
public class AppRunCookie
{
    public static string CookieName { get; set; }
    public static string Key { get; set; }
public AppRunCookie(string key)
{
    CookieName = "MyCookie_" + key;
}

public static void SetCookie(string key, int cookieExpireDate = 30)
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(CookieName);
    myCookie["Key"] = key;
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(cookieExpireDate);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}

public string GetCookie()
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CookieName];
    if (myCookie != null)
    {
        string key = Convert.ToString(myCookie.Values["Key"]);
        return key;
    }
    return "";
}
}
```

What am I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't use" exactly? What is your error message? If you are using Visual Studio, you can let VS create missing using statements by selecting the line with the error, pressing ctrl+. and selecting the appropriate option.

Comment: @TimPohlmann I found some tutorials on stackoverflow. In this tutorial they used the HttpCookie statement. I tried to implement this in my own project. VB2015 tell me this: “the type or namespace HttpCookie could not be found....” You’re right VB give in normal cases some “to does” but in this case VB give no “to does” The HttpContext-method can I already use because I follow the “to does” of VB. Is this because I use the latest .NET Core?

Comment: VB? I assume you mean VS (aka Visual Studio). Weird that it does not propose the usings.

Comment: @TimPohlmann sorry my mistake :D i mean VS for Visual Studio :)

Comment: If you are using ASP.Net MVC then beware that the HttpContext is under the Controller section as the page life cycle is changed using that framework. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 may be useful for more details.

Comment: @JBKing thank you for your answer. I found [this](http://senvichet.com/blog/how-to-create-get-asp-net-core-cookie/#) and I tried it but it isn’t work  C# don’t know the `CookieOption`-Method. Back to your answer: C# don’t know `System.Web` and for this reason `System.Web.mvc’  too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So Hello guys

I found a solution, try to use [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0) wonderful blog entry.

**Note:**
Make sure you install the nuget-packages via the nuget installer and make also sure you checked the checkbox “include prerelease”.

Hope my poste was helpful

Comment: That article is for implementing Session. But if you want to implement cookie handling I recommend to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace and the following classes Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions

Answer (score 4):

The namespace for `HttpContext` and `HttpCookie` is `System.Web` which is part of the `System.Web.dll` library.

Go right click the projects `References` and select `Add References...`. In the newly opened window click on `Assemblies` and then search (via the search bar in the upper right) for `System.Web`.

Then you should be able to use it via

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: As per @JB King's comment on the OP, the `HttpContext` will be in the scope of a controller. So, although `using System.Web` will give you access to the `HttpContext` object, it will not be in the same scope as the rest of the app - as the `HttpContext` is in the scope of the Controllers

Comment: @GeoffJames watch my comment

Comment: @Yannikhere I don't know why the assembly is missing for you, sorry.

Comment: @TimPohlmann ;( I created a normal ASP.NET Core webapplication lol. Can you open my project an try if it work by you, please [github]( https://github.com/YannikG/eCoffee/tree/master/eCoffee) IIf you done give me please a feedback… I will commit the latest version wait...

Comment: @Yannikhere My guess is, it has something to do with the project being an ASP.NET Core webapplication. I'm not familiar with those. In a regular C# project my solution works just fine.

Comment: @TimPohlmann and I'm a IT-trainee :) ok no problem I think i found [something](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-core-1-0)