# HttpCookie class in aspnet core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm converting a .net 4.7 MVC project to .net core 2, attempting to preserve as much of the code, as is, as possible. This project has a `BaseService` that *builds* an `AuthCookie` that's consumed by a few other services throughout the application.

```
// Create
public HttpCookie AuthCookie { get; set; } = new HttpCookie(AuthUtils.CookieName);

// Consume
if (AuthCookie?.Value != null) { ... }
```

In .net 4.7, the `HttpCookie` class is included in the `System.Web` namespace, but doesn't seem to exist in .net core 2 in the same way. As in, a cookie is built and handled outside the context of a controller.

I've seen:
[Why I can't use HttpContext or HttpCookie? (Asp.Net Core 1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346333/why-i-cant-use-httpcontext-or-httpcookie-asp-net-core-1-0)

That doesn't seem to address this question. Is the fundamental difference in authentication handling in .net core so big that this case can't be handled?

Comment: go through this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

Comment: Try using CookieBuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:~:text=Properties%20%20%20Domain%20%20%20The%20domain,for%20the%20cookie.%20%204%20more%20rows%20