# How to correctly set cookies (HttpCookie) for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcookie

Below are a few different ways I'm trying to set cookies for a user. I don't understand why I'm getting an error on the HttpCookie. If someone knows what I'm doing wrong please let me know or if you need more details on my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @AverageGuyIssac, does your project using `asp.net-mvc` or `asp.net-core-mvc`? Both frameworks are different.

Comment: @YongShun I am using asp.net-core-mvc

Comment: Hi @AveargeGuyIssac, your question is same as [HttpCookie class in aspnet core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48495314/8017690). You can read this post & also its linked duplicate questions as well. Thanks.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code and other textual content as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  It's preferred not to use images for this purpose here, see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812) for why.

Answer (score 4):

Download Package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http** using Nuget Package Manager,
refer this package in your class by writing **using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;**

Instead of HTTPCookie class ,You need to use CookieOptions Class as follow

`CookieOptions langCookie=new CookieOptions(); langCookie.Expires=DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);`