# How to set a raw cookie value in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I would like to set the value of `mycookie` to `value=somevalue`, thus:

[image: cookie view in chome]

The recommended approach of using `Cookies.Append` does not work, as the value is URL encoded and ends up being `value%3Dsomevalue`.

My code for adding the cookie:

```
_context.Response.Cookies.Append("mycookie", $"value=somevalue");
```

My code for reading the cookie

```
_context.Request.Cookies["mycookie"]
```

The question: what would be the best way to bypass the URL encoding and set the raw value of the cookie?

Comment: How about creating the cookie using `HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("mycookie");` and then setting the value as `MyCookie.Value = somevalue` and then adding it as `context.Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);`

Comment: `HttpCookie` used to part of the `System.Web` for the old ASP.NET. I am not aware of any `HttpCookie` class in ASP.NET Core. Using the old way would require access to another `HttpContext` which I would prefer to avoid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346333/why-i-cant-use-httpcontext-or-httpcookie-asp-net-core-1-0.

Comment: Then how about not giving the `value=` itself, just try _context.Response.Cookies.Append("mycookie", "somevalue");

Comment: This works fine, but I do need the `value=` in there. I just don't want the `=` to be URL encoded.

Answer (score 1):

I found a reasonable workaround, by setting the cookie header manually.

```
_context.Response.Headers.Append("Set-Cookie", "mycookie=value=somevalue");
```

You can use the same code to get the cookie back:

```
_context.Request.Cookies["mycookie"]
```